# How does bsreach works in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

Since a week back from now I started to learn ruby. In array, I couldn't understand how the below statements works?
I have an Array of integers i.e.

```
ary = [0, 4, 7, 10, 12]
puts ary.bsearch {|x| 1 - x/4 }  
puts ary.bsearch {|x| 2 - x / 3 }

output :
4
7
```

Please explain.

Comment: @jordan: please explain me **|x| 1 - x/4**  and **|x| 2 - x / 3** statements work

Comment: http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_blocks.html

Comment: The linked answer explains better than I could. If you're still having trouble, take out a pencil and paper and work it step by step.